# Use a component on both React and Angular

Tags: reactjs, angular, npm, components

We're currently maintaining multiple projects that has the same implementation of a navigation bar. These projects differ on which JS Libraries they're built on (namely React, Angular and Angular JS). I was just wondering if there are ways that I could make a single share-able component across these projects (e.g., NPM package maybe?) so that it would be easier for maintenance and applying changes on the component would take effect on all pages.

Comment: Maybe [micro-frontends](https://micro-frontends.org/)?

Comment: @mee after reading through micro frontends, it seems that it's the other way around of what I want to do. what I want is a single component for different JS Libraries on different repositories.

Answer (score 0):

You provided a minimal context for our case. What can I say?

1. You could pick one stack for shared components - react or angular. And use it in all projects. React can provide a div element, that can be use angular shared component for mounting, and angular app can do the same for react shared component.
2. You can write shared components by WebComponents stack. These components will be follow our design system. But it require to create 2 wrappers: 1 for react, for angular.

```
// monorep/webcomponents
class CommonComponent extends HTMLElement {}



// monorep/react-components
const CommonComponentReact (props) => {
// react specific logic
  return <common-component attr and props />
}

// monorep/angular-components
// angular the same as react
```

So you can pick any stack for base(shared) components instead webcomponens. All what you need to do it create wrappers for external stack